# How to Recoverer domain verification email sent by ICANN

Tags: email, icann

My registar had a problem and was doing maintenance when ICANN sent an email verification of the domain I had just bought. Consequently, I did not receive the mail and my domain has just been suspended. I would like to know how to get this email. If you have other alternatives for me, thank you for helping me.

Comment: ICANN does not send any email verification. Registrars do.

Answer (score 0):

Contact the service you used to register the domain. They should be able to get you in touch with the people necessary to reinstate / verify the domain.